# CSS was not rendering in the IIS server

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

CSS was loaded to web when using visual studio IIS express. when i deploy to my local IIS, the css was not render fully. IIS static was on.

Another thing i noticed was that if i point my web path in IIS to my development folder. it works fine also.

i use visual studio build in public with file system to public the web.

**Correct CSS header**
[image]

**Problem CSS header**
[image]

**Updated**
       public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Comment: Are you using bundling? If so, when debugging (and using IIS Express) have you set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations`? This appears to be normal behaviour between debug and release when using bundling.

Comment: yes i am using bundling.do i add that to first line to bundle?

Comment: added code    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; to my registerbundle. still the same

Comment: Go through your bundle definition code (often in `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs`) and check you're including all the correct CSS files in the correct order there. If done right bundling will make no difference to the effect of styles but be quicker and use fewer resources.

Comment: hi. i tried setting budinletable.enableoptimizations=false and it works. Thanks for helping me pointing the direction.

Comment: Converted above comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using ASP.NET-MVC with its standard CSS/JS bundling support.

By setting `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` or not depending on build configuration you can switch from debug (no minification and bundling: good for debugging) to release (minimise number of files by bundling and size by minifying).

It looks like things are working correctly.

If you are seeing different behaviour then it is likely you need to fix your bundle configurations (ordering is significant).

The easiest route is to always use bundling for all CSS and JS served from your server, and use the above switch to disable when debugging.